# Is there any way to allow a browser to search "hidden" text on a page (or an image's alt text)?

Tags: html, css

I have [a page on my website](http://www.pricewombat.com/start-here) that has a bunch of retailer logos on it. I would like for users to be able to search for a retailer using their browser's search feature, but I don't have the retailers' names in text on the page, just their logo.

The behavior I'm looking for is where a user types a retailer's name into their browser's search box (for the page) and the browser jumps down to the retailer's logo. The behavior would also be really useful for things like image galleries.

From the searching I've done I don't think this is possible, but is there any way to have "hidden" text on the page that the browser can search, or to make the browser search an image's alt text, without having visible text on the page?

Comment: I think you would need to create your own custom search box rather than relying on the built in search. Only other alternative would be sub optimal things like adding small text with the same font colour as page background next to the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trick that might work is to surround each image with a container, e.g. `div.box`, and to give it an additional child, e.g. `div.search-text`. The container is used to allow the search text to be absolutely positioned on top of the image. The search-text is filled with the text to search on and is styled in such a way that it isn't visible, but does allow to be searched on.

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}

.search-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Or see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/EaPZZO where I've enumerated each kitten. Try searching on e.g. *Five* or *Two*.

But you probably need to do extensive cross browser testing. I assume that every browser has its own logic to decide when a piece of text can be searched on (Chrome for example didn't like searching when the text had `font-size: 0` but didn't have any problems with `opacity: 0`

Answer (score 1):

you can have text in div -at same position as image and hide it by using z-index. Along with z-index you can use color text matchig with background.